# Accessing tweets from home timeline in Twitter using oAuth in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to print the first tweet in the user timeline.

`$hometimeline = $twitterObj->get_statusesHome_timeline();

$stream=$hometimeline->responseText;

$user=$stream[0]->user;

$tweet=$user->text;

echo $tweet;`

This just won't print anything. What am I doing wrong here?

If I echo `$hometimeline->responseText`  it shows on the screen
[
{"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null, "coordinates":null, "geo":null, "user":{"profile_use_background_image":true,"text":"I am back",....},"id_str":"121212"},

{ ... so on}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$hometimeline = $twitterObj->get_statusesHome_timeline();
$stream = json_decode( $hometimeline->responseText );
$user=$stream[0]->user;
$tweet=$user->text;
echo $tweet;
```

json_decode turns the JSON string that you are receiving into a PHP object.

Comment: After the `$stream = ...` line do `print_r( $stream ); exit;` and see what comes out.

Comment: something like `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [coordinates] => [geo] => [user] => stdClass Object ( [is_translator] => [default_profile] => [profile_use_background_image] => 1 [protected] => [follow_request_sent] => [statuses_count] => 14439 [friends_count] => 69 [profile_background_color] => ffffff ...... `       I also tried using $stream[0]["user"]["text"] but that results in error

Comment: You can see that `$stream[0]->user` is an object of type StdClass and that it has various properties (`is_translator`, `statuses_count`, `friends_count`, etc.) so the decode is working but you haven't included enough to see whether the user has a `text` property. If `$stream[0]->user->text` doesn't have a value then either you have got the name of the property wrong or the value for this particular instance is actually empty.

Comment: ahh let me get on this in a couple of minutes

Comment: aargh....you are right, text isn't really part of the user object, all i had to do is $stream[0]->text ... so sorry about this

Comment: How come when I use $twitterInfo= $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials(); , I dont have to decode the json response & I can directly use `echo $twitterInfo->screen_name;` ??

Comment: That will be down to whoever made the $twitterObj code that you are using. Presumably the get_accountVerify_credentials() method has the json_decode() built in.

Answer (score 2):

you are getting a json string as response. Use [json_decode](http://ar.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) to parse the response and you will be able to manage it as array o stdobject

do this just before interact with the response

```
$stream = json_decode( $hometimeline->responseText, true);
```

### Edit

remember you can always use [print_r](http://ar.php.net/print_r) to debug

Comment: I don't think I should have to decode this. I should be able to access JSON values directly shouldn't I. Like in case of $twitterInfo->screen_name will directly give me the screenname from the JSON response.

Comment: no. you need at least run `json_decode` once. the fact of you using the response as object or array depends of if you put `true` or not as a second argument of `json_decode`